# Aligning text on edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, edge

I cannot figure out why the text on the edge is not entered. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] (r1) {};;

\node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, right=3cm of r1] (r2) {} edge[<-,thick] node[above,text width=1.5cm, align=center] {Asynchronous\\[-3pt]replication} (r1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `text width` setting:

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] (r1) {};;

\node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, right=3cm of r1] (r2) {} edge[<-,thick] node[above, align=center] {Asynchronous\\[-3pt]replication} (r1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A 1.5 cm text width is smaller than the width:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much; I thought that would allow the multiple lines, but it is not the case.

Comment: @ozsu You're welcome, you can do that, but you need to have the enough length set for `text width`, and the `\\[-3pt]` won't be needed for line breaking.